# How to align text in JTextField?

Tags: java, jtextfield

Here is my code:

```
try{
    Font font1=new Font("SansSerif",Font.ITALIC,20);
    JTextField levi=new JTextField(20);
    levi.setBounds(107,10,246,100);
    levi.setForeground(Color.black);
    levi.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    levi.setFont(font1);
    levi.setBorder(nue);
    lin.add(levi);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

When I run the program i got this exception [image: exception]

Comment: instead of doing a JOptionPane, try doing `ex.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and showing us the stacktrace or debug it. If I had to guess, you are getting the problem at `levi.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);` and setting an invalid attribute for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29) for `JTextField`, the only valid keys for the `setHorizontalAlignment()` method are:

> ```
> JTextField.LEFT
> JTextField.CENTER
> JTextField.RIGHT
> JTextField.LEADING
> JTextField.TRAILING
> ```

Passing in `SwingConstants.BOTTOM` will throw an exception.

Comment: Not working as in getting an exception? Or not working as in the behavior is not what you want?

Comment: Now it's working but i want text at the bottom of the textfield